# SharePoint unfamiliar error on kw search: SubstrateSearchException: Remote executors failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, keyword-search

We run a classic JavaScript app on multiple tenants on SharePoint online.  The app uses the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery to search for documents within the site collection where the app is installed. On one of the systems we get the error:

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.SubstrateSearch.SubstrateSearchException:
> Remote executors failed, local failback not allowed.

Despite the specific words in the error message, I was not able to find any documentation about its meaning. When I copy the search string used in the SP search field the search works. Any clues what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Any developments on this? We just started seeing this same error in one dev environment but not another, despite running the same code.

[image: Error log]

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem, but if I include "-contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary" in the keyword query it works, but since i need items from document libraries this wont help me.

We have only seen this issue one one environment, I am not sure how to fix it. It looks like it is having issues with document libraries specifically, unless i include a some text it also should search for (besides the keywords). If i didn't know any better i would almost say it was some kind of overflow, but that just seems far fetched, and we do have limits on the query anyway.

Update:
Subsequently if I wrote a keyword for a specific library like ListId:73C91192-89CD-4C06-A322-388CEAE456ED instead, it also works

Comment: For us only adding 'modifiedBy: ...' makes it work, but we also need the query without this filter part.

Answer (score 0):

we just recently started to see this same issue.

In our case we were using a Classic SharePoint Online site, with the search web parts on it.  The search results web part had a number of different Hit-highlighted managed properties that it was trying to bring back.  One of these properties was "Topic".  I checked the search schema and for some reason, this managed property had disappeared.  Removing this property from the search results web part fixed the page and search results web part.

No one had touched our search schema in a long time so this property had simply disappeared.  Definitely seems like search schema updates are causing issues.

[Hit-highlighted properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3joR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does anybody have some usefull information or pointers on this issue? We just came across this issue on one tenant for one specific user. We have a multi-tenant app that executes a search query looking for document libraries with 3 conditions:

1. We do use the ContentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary condition as we are looking for document libraries
2. External content specifier: "-isexternalcontent:1"
3. Generic search term: just a single word

As mentioned we get this error on one tenant when one specific user executes it. I can't reproduce it with other user accounts. Since we are providing a multi-tenant SaaS we are afraid this will start popping up for our customers..